# Trying to change the names of Asp.net Identity tables MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I want to change the default names of ap.net identity tables. I have few questions in my mind

1) Will that be possible if the tables already created and have some data

2) Can we just change the names of table and keep the data as it is

I have tried this code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("MyUsers").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("MyUsers").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("MyUserRoles");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("MyUserLogins");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("MyUserClaims");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("MyRoles");
}
```

but it throws me model backing context has changed error

```
The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database
```

Comment: What error do you get ? post the error.

Comment: The `<ApplicationUser>` line (2nd down), in particular, is important if you don't want to have a dangling `AspNetUsers` table with only an `ID` in it. That line re-focuses ApplicationUser to the new MyUsers table.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to disable initializers. I turned it off as I prefer to maintain my database and code. 
E.g.

```
Database.SetInitializer<Entities>( null );
```

You could also keep the model names as they are if you want to and specify the table name explicitly in the model, e.g:

```
[Table( "NewTableName" )]
internal class OldTableName
{
    ....
}
```